# Streaming from a YouTube (live) channel

Tags: android, video-streaming

I want to stream a **live** channel from YouTube into my app. See an example of a live channel here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oObdPuriO2w

I don't want to use Intent and the YouTube app in the device. I don't want to depend on it. I read about streaming on Stack Overflow, but I got confused!

1. Do I use `WebView` or `VideoView` or `MediaPlayer` or what?
2. I read something about [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol). What is it? Do I need to use it?
3. What are the clear steps of what I need to implement?

---

To those who might be interested:

I couldn't find a solution to my problem. So, I gave up on that project!

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this code...

```
WebView video = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.video);

video.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
video.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
video.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oObdPuriO2w");
```

Note: To stream video on your device, flashplayer must be updated.

Comment: This code opens the browser to play the video from Youtube's mobile version ! It is strange. We didn't use `Intent` !!

Comment: ya.. and i think it is usefull to you as you don't want to use intent..

Comment: Ok. Let's make it clear: I do NOT want to use apps other than mine.

Answer (score 0):

About the intents opening, I think that one of the following lines might help avoiding it:

```
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptInterface()
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
      {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)
        {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
        }
      }
```

...